# Unable to open COM port using phpSerial with XAMPP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am using [phpSerial](https://github.com/Xowap/PHP-Serial) to communicate on a COM port (COM10).

Here is my code: (very similar to the [example code](https://github.com/Xowap/PHP-Serial/blob/develop/examples/dummy.php))

```
<?php
require('php_serial.class.php');

echo "<html>
      <head><title>Test MySQL</title></head>
      <body>";

// Let's start the class
$serial = new phpSerial;

$serial->deviceSet("COM10");

$serial->confBaudRate(1200);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(7);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$serial->deviceOpen();

$serial->sendMessage("Hello !");

$read = $serial->readPort();

echo "here it is";
echo $read;
echo "here it was";

sleep(1);

$serial->deviceClose();

?>
</body></html>
```

This is the response I get it runs:

```
Warning: Specified serial port is not valid in D:\xampp\htdocs\Serialport\PHP-Serial-develop\PHP-Serial-develop\php_serial.class.php on line 141

Warning: Unable to set the baud rate : the device is either not set or opened in D:\xampp\htdocs\Serialport\PHP-Serial-develop\PHP-Serial-develop\php_serial.class.php on line 234

Warning: Unable to set parity : the device is either not set or opened in D:\xampp\htdocs\Serialport\PHP-Serial-develop\PHP-Serial-develop\php_serial.class.php on line 288

Warning: Unable to set length of a character : the device is either not set or opened in D:\xampp\htdocs\Serialport\PHP-Serial-develop\PHP-Serial-develop\php_serial.class.php on line 336

Warning: Unable to set the length of a stop bit : the device is either not set or opened in D:\xampp\htdocs\Serialport\PHP-Serial-develop\PHP-Serial-develop\php_serial.class.php on line 377

Warning: The device must be set before to be open in D:\xampp\htdocs\Serialport\PHP-Serial-develop\PHP-Serial-develop\php_serial.class.php on line 167

Warning: Device must be opened in D:\xampp\htdocs\Serialport\PHP-Serial-develop\PHP-Serial-develop\php_serial.class.php on line 608

Warning: Device must be opened to read it in D:\xampp\htdocs\Serialport\PHP-Serial-develop\PHP-Serial-develop\php_serial.class.php on line 522

here it ishere it was
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

My device is connected to COM10 and shows as *Silicon Labs CP210x USB to UART Bridge(COM10)*

Comment: Are you sure your device is connected to COM10. Could you check your serial port and what is your device?

Comment: ya sure my device connected to COM10..my device is"Silicon Labs CP210x USB to UART Bridge(COM10) "

Comment: Since you're under windows, you may be up against the different ways that COM ports equal to and above COM10 are accessed. Can't tell without looking at the source for the library or by simply trying it. As such, you should try using \\.\COM10 instead of COM10 - since you'd have to escape the slashes, you'd need to use the following string "\\\\.\\COM10" (if indeed this is the problem). For more, see here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/115831 **EDIT** Just looked at the source - my $5 bet says this _is_ the problem. The library simply uses fopen along with the COM port name.

Comment: can you please tell me correctly..i did't read serial port..that same warning displaying to me

Comment: @karthickkannan - you mean me? (put an @ in front of a user name to ensure they get notified) If so, can you say that in a different way as I don't quite understand what you're asking/telling me. :)

Comment: @karthickkannan Got any solution for this issue.? I need help on the same.

Comment: @karthickkannan